# How to byte reverse NSData output in Swift the littleEndian way?

Tags: swift, nsdata, endianness

I have this output from NSData: <00000100 84000c00 071490fe 4dfbd7e9>

So how could I byte reverse it in Swift and have this output: <00000001 0084000c 1407fe90 fb4de9d7>?

Comment: is there anyway we can determine NSData is bigEndian or Little-Endian format?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work to swap each pair of adjacent bytes in the data.
The idea is to interpret the bytes as an array of `UInt16` integers
and use the built-in `byteSwapped` property.

```
func swapUInt16Data(data : NSData) -> NSData {
    
    // Copy data into UInt16 array:
    let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt16)
    var array = [UInt16](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&array, length: count * sizeof(UInt16))
    
    // Swap each integer:
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        array[i] = array[i].byteSwapped // *** (see below)
    }

    // Create NSData from array:
    return NSData(bytes: &array, length: count * sizeof(UInt16))
}
```

If your actual intention is to convert data from an (external)
big-endian representation to the host (native) byte order (which happens to be little-endian on all current iOS and OS X devices) then you should replace `***` by

```
array[i] = UInt16(bigEndian: array[i])
```

Example:

```
var bytes : [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let data = NSData(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count)
print(data)
// <01020304 05060708>
print(swapUInt16Data(data))
// <02010403 06050807>
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:** The generic `withUnsafeMutableBytes()`
methods allows to obtain a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>` to the bytes
and modify them directly:

```
func swapUInt16Data(data : Data) -> Data {
    var mdata = data // make a mutable copy
    let count = data.count / MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
    mdata.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (i16ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>) in
        for i in 0..<count {
            i16ptr[i] =  i16ptr[i].byteSwapped
        }
    }
    return mdata
}
```

Example:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
print(data as NSData) // <01020304 05060708>

let swapped = swapUInt16Data(data: data)
print(swapped as NSData) // <02010403 06050807>
```

---

**Update for Swift 5,** (fixing a deprecated warning):

```
func swapUInt16Data(data : Data) -> Data {
    var mdata = data // make a mutable copy
    let count = data.count / MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
    mdata.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
        let i16ptr = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self)
        for i in 0..<count {
            i16ptr[i] =  i16ptr[i].byteSwapped
        }
    }
    return mdata
}
```

Comment: Got this error: "Cannot invoke 'reverse' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>)'" on line var reversedBytes = reverse(bytes).

Comment: Well the first code I get that error and can't compile. The second code works, but does not correctly byte reverse because it reverses like backwards and what I want it if raw NSData output is 45 F4 67 C3, then I want: F4 45 C3 67. I think this is littleEndian.

Comment: @Marco: Strange, it worked in my XCode 6.3.1. But I will double-check when I am at my computer again. – Endianness conversion is a different thing, that wasn't obvious from your question.

Comment: @MartinR, where is the reverse() function defined? And documented? It's a function that takes an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>` and returns another `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>` containing the reversed byte-stream?

Comment: Sorry @Sulthan and Martin R. I have edited the question.

Comment: @DuncanC: Unsafe(Mutable)BufferPointer conforms to CollectionType, that's why it can be reverse()'ed. The result is an *array* of the corresponding element type.

Comment: Martin, thanks for explaining that. Now can you explain where you found byteSwapped? I can't find it in the SwiftDoc.org page the Swift standard library reference, or either of the Swift iBooks. The only way I can find it is to put it in source code in Xcode and command-click on it. I see that it's a computed property defined on UInt16, but I have never heard of it before today. Where do you learn about all this stuff?!?

Comment: @DuncanC actually it's on the page http://swiftdoc.org/type/UInt16/ at the instance variables section.

Comment: @MartinR Can you please update your great answer to Swift3 and with the "Data" object? (not NSData) Simple conversion tries didn't work

Comment: @MatanGold: Done :)

Comment: @MartinR I have a problem when I try to swap odd number of bytes. I have Data object of length 19 and after the swap I get 18 (dropping the last one) - Is there something can be done? (Here's Hex rep. of the odd data: "AA AA 11 12 0D 00 00 00 01 00 00 02 00 04 00 AC F0 44 3F")

Comment: @MatanGold: Yes, the above code assumes that the number of bytes is even. What result would you expect for the last byte in your case?

Comment: @MartinR just leave it as it is (This will keep original data length)

Comment: @MatanGold: See update. The last version was actually wrong, it modified the first values only.

Comment: @MartinR Perfect! Gr8!

Comment: Thanx @MartinR, It Does Work for me, my only problem is it send a deprecated warning.    "withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead".  kindly can you write another update for swift 5 too, thanx again and good job.

Comment: @AhmedEl-Bermawy: Updated for Swift 5.

Comment: @MartinR, Fantastic Work.

Answer (score 3):

CoreFoundation has `CFSwapInt32BigToHost` and `CFSwapInt32LittleToHost` and other swap functions.

In swift3 it looks like this

```
struct FileHeader {
    var magicNumber: UInt32 = 0
    var count: UInt32 = 0
    var width: UInt32 = 0
    var height: UInt32 = 0

    static func create(data: Data) -> FileHeader {
        let structSize = MemoryLayout<FileHeader>.size
        assert(data.count >= structSize)
        var result = FileHeader()
        let nsdata = data as NSData
        nsdata.getBytes(&result, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: structSize))
        result.magicNumber = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(result.magicNumber)
        result.count = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(result.count)
        result.width = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(result.width)
        result.height = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(result.height)
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying the `data` to a `FileHeader` structure can be simplified to `var result: FileHeader = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }` without the need for an intermediate `NSData` (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415). – Byte swapping can alternatively be done with "native" Swift methods, e.g. `result.magicNumber = UInt32(bigEndian: result.magicNumber)`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone may want to restrict the byte pattern, it would be a solution:

```
func swap<U:IntegerType>(data:NSData,_ :U.Type) -> NSData{
    var length = data.length / sizeof(U)
    var bytes = [U](count: length, repeatedValue: 0)
    data.getBytes(&bytes, length: data.length)
    // since byteSwapped isn't declare in any protocol, so we have do it by ourselves manually.
    var inverse = bytes.enumerate().reduce([U](count: length, repeatedValue: 0)) { (var pre, ele) -> [U] in
        pre[length - 1 - ele.index] = ele.element
        return pre
    }
    return NSData(bytes: inverse, length: data.length)
}
```

for example:

```
swap(data:data,UInt8.self)
//before <0c20207b 17> 
//after <177b2020 0c>

swap(data:anotherData,UInt16.self)
//before <8e004c01 84008f05 0701>
//after <07018f05 84004c01 8e00>
```