# Little endian bitmaps & "Unable to create GMSGLImageTile due to bad graphics data"

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but I'm attempting to render radar tiles over a Google Maps map and am receiving the following messages:

- ((null)) was false: Unable to create GMSGLImageTile due to bad graphics data
- ((null)) was false: Don't support little endian bitmaps

Is there an easy way to convert a `UIImage` to a big endian or is there something I need to know about using / subclassing `GMSSyncTileLayer`?

The images I'm trying to render as tiles are png images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error will occur if your PNG images for your tiles are not set to 8-bit color depth.

Changing the color depth of your images to 8-bits should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only the big-little endian problem, yes. Did you get the bitmap by NSDate or is it possible to create one? If so, convert it to a bytes array then swap the bits.

*Edited

Me and the other guys have made some answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051250/1900120

Comment: I tried writing a method that would swap that bits, but the image got really mangled. It was taking a really long time to figure out what was going on, so we ended up using a different implementation that served 8-bit images. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: You are welcome Brian. I'm so curious about your implementation~ Is it a data structure and algo that special designed for converting the underlay bits? Please give me a hint if you don't mind since those info may help so many of us in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This reference where reported and answered about your question

https://github.com/domesticmouse/swift-google-map

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8787