# Swift 3 and Xcode8 - Ambiguous use of init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Before I installed Xcode 8 and converted project to Swift 3, the following line was fine. Now after conversion it looks like this:

```
let valueData:Data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(&intVal), count: sizeof(NSInteger))
```

it shows the error

> Ambiguous use of 'init'

what is wrong with it in Swift 3? How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to create `Data` from a simple value is to go via
`UnsafeBufferPointer`, then you don't need any explicit pointer conversion or size calculation:

```
var intVal = 1000
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &intVal, count: 1))
print(data as NSData) // <e8030000 00000000>
```

For a more generic approach for conversion from values to `Data`
and back, see for example [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data).

Comment: Problem for me trying to get a pointer to an element in array &buffer[offset]. This answer fails with "cannot subscript a value of inout[UInt8]". Alternative answer using withUnsafePointer works fine

Answer (score 8):

`UnsafePointer` has initializer for both `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer`, and sizeof was moved to `MemoryLayout` disambiguate it as:

```
let valueData = withUnsafePointer(to: &intVal){
    return Data(bytes: $0, count: MemoryLayout<NSInteger>.size)
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me (and not the accepted answer).

Comment: @i4niac: I have double-checked that both answers work with the current Xcode 8.2.1 (and produce the same result). Please let me know if there is a problem with my answer. How does it not work? Do you get an error or a wrong result?

Comment: In my case I have an array of UInt8 and need a pointer to &buffer[offset]. This answer works, but using UnsafeBufferPointer as per the accepted answer does not