# Using NSFileHandle on Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nsfilehandle

How could I write this method in Swift 3?

```
extension NSFileHandle {
    func readUInt32() -> UInt32? {
        let data = self.readDataOfLength(4)
        guard data.length == 4 else { return nil }
        return CFSwapInt32HostToBig(UnsafePointer<UInt32>(data.bytes).memory)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extension FileHandle {
    func readUInt32() -> UInt32? {
        let data = self.readData(ofLength: 4)
        guard data.count == 4 else { return nil }
        return UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
    }
}
```

Reading from a `FileHandle` returns a `Data` value. 
`data.withUnsafeBytes` calls the closure with a pointer to the
bytes, here the type of the pointer `$0` is inferred from the context
as `UnsafePointer<UInt32>`.

`UInt32(bigEndian:)` creates an integer from its big-endian
representation, as an alternative to `CFSwapInt32BigToHost()`.

For more examples on how to convert from/to `Data`, see for example
[round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data).