# How to convert Data to Int in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

There're a lot of sources explaining how to make it in **Swift 2** which I took as a base:

```
var value: Int = 0
let data: NSData = ...;
data.getBytes(&value, length: sizeof(Int))
```

Then I updated syntax/naming due to **Swift 3**:

```
var value: Int = 0
let data: NSData = ...;
data.copyBytes(to: &value, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
```

Nevertheless it doesn't work. The compiler doesn't like the type of `value`, it says it should be `UInt8`. But I want `Int`. Anybody knows how can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that copying raw data into an int is fragile. If you try to exchange values between platforms with different "endian-ness" you will get the wrong result. iOS devices, Macs, and Windows PCs are all little-endian, but other hardware is big-endian.

Comment: Have a look at [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll pay attention to your points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try like this:

```
var src: Int = 12345678
var num: Int = 0 // initialize

let data = NSData(bytes: &src, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
data.getBytes(&num, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
print(num) // 12345678
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I've tried this, it gives a compile error `'getBytes(_:length:)' has been renamed to 'copyBytes(to:count:)'`. In the same time it works in a playground. Strange.

Comment: Yes that is strange; which version of Xcode are you using? I'm on 8.2 and it compiles without issue. I did notice that when I copied my code I used `NSInteger` instead of `Int`, but doubtful that has an effect.

Comment: Mine is 8.1. Does it work for you in a project?

Comment: Yep, works in a project and a playground both...

Comment: Cool, I'll update and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko: I was able to reproduce the issue you have. Are you calling `NSData` or just `Data`? This is where things change... It appears that specifically using `NSData` there doesn't seem to have the issue, however, `Data` only allows `UInt8` and exhibits the same behavior as in your question.

Comment: Use `Data` and not `NSData`