# How to convert Data/NSData to an Array of Integers using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I have a Data that I received from a characteristic in a Service

```
let value = characteristic.value
```

This "value" of type Data .

In this value there are 20 bytes that contains 5 numbers of type Uint8 or int  1,2,3,4,5.

How do I get these Integer numbers from this Data value???

Comment: Why is this tagged with Bluetooth tags?

Comment: Because the data i got is from BLE, I can un tag it

Comment: Hi @nicko_yuan bro, check this if work `let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(value, options:[])`

Comment: Have a look at [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) If you have stingyfy josn(Come from API response) then you can convert to directly to `[Int]` using..

```
do {
    let IntArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataObject, options:[])
    print(IntArray)
    // print: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
}catch{
    print("Error in Serialization")
}
```

2) If you want `[Int] and Data` conversion then use this

You can create `Data` from `[Int]` using 'archivedData' and back to '[Int]' using `unarchiveObject`.

```
var listOfInt : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

let dataObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: listOfInt)

if let objects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dataObject) as? [Int] {
    print(objects)
    // print: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
} else {
    print("Error while unarchiveObject")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert Data/NSData to an array of Integer

```
// here value is Data type which contain array of byte
let value = characteristic.value

let B0 = value[0]
let B1 = value[1]
let B2 = value[2]
let B3 = value[3]
let B4 = value[4]
let B5 = value[5]

// create a byte of array
let generationByteData: [UInt8] = [B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5]
print("generationByteData = \(generationByteData)")

// Result = generationByteData = [3, 17, 34, 0, 0, 0]
```