# How can I convert data into types like Doubles, Ints and Strings in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm working on building a custom file opener in iOS Swift for shapefiles (a GIS format, not particularly relevant to this question).  These files have a header which is 100 bytes long.  I'm able to read this into 4-byte arrays, which store information I want.  I can convert these arrays into the Swift types `Data` and `NSData`, and have a few other options for transforming them (like `Base64EncodedString`).  But I'm having trouble converting these raw arrays or the Data or any of the formats into useful attributes like `Double`, `Int`, and `String`.

```
import Foundation
    struct ShapeReader {
        var shapeFile = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "/Users/christopherjlowrie/Documents/Shapes/SF_Neighborhoods/Planning_Zones.shp")
        var fileHeader: String{
            let header = shapeFile?.readData(ofLength: 100)
            let headerStream = InputStream(data: header!)
            headerStream.open()
            var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
            while (headerStream.hasBytesAvailable){
                headerStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                print(buffer)
                let x = Data(buffer)
                print(x)
        }
        return "A"
    }
}
```

*This currently only returns A because for testing reasons I am having it return a string*

How can I open files, and read their raw bytes into types (`Doubles`, `Ints`, `Strings`) in Swift?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1 or later**

To convert from `String` to `DataProtocol` (Data or Bytes):

```
extension DataProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    init<S: StringProtocol>(_ string: S) {
        self.init(string.utf8)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var data: Data { .init(self) }
    var bytes: [UInt8] { .init(self) }
}
```

---

To convert from `DataProtocol` back to `String`

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var string: String? { String(bytes: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

---

```
let stringData = "abc".data               // 3 bytes
let stringBytes = "abc".bytes             // [97, 98, 99]
let stringFromData = stringData.string    // "abc"
let stringFromBytes = stringBytes.string  // "abc"
```

---

---

To convert from any `Numeric` type to `DataProtocol`:

```
extension DataProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    init<N: Numeric>(_ numeric: N) {
        self = withUnsafeBytes(of: numeric) { .init($0) }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var data: Data { .init(self) }
    var bytes: [UInt8] { .init(self) }
}
```

---

To convert from `DataProtocol` back to any `Numeric` type:

```
extension Numeric {
    init<D: DataProtocol>(_ data: D) {
        var value: Self = .zero
        let size = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, data.copyBytes)
        self = value
    }
}
```

---

```
extension DataProtocol {
    func value<N: Numeric>() -> N { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
let value = 12.34                      // implicit Double 12.34
let data = value.data                  // double data - 8 bytes
let bytes = value.bytes                // [113, 61, 10, 215, 163, 16, 69, 64]
let double = Double(data)              // implicit Double 12.34
let double1: Double = .init(data)      // explicit Double 12.34
let double2: Double = data.value()     // explicit Double 12.34
let double3 = data.value() as Double   // casting to Double 12.34
```

---

Now we can easily add a property for each `Numeric` type:

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var integer: Int { value() }
    var int32: Int32 { value() }
    var float: Float { value() }
    var cgFloat: CGFloat { value() }
    var float80: Float80 { value() }
    var double: Double { value() }
    var decimal: Decimal { value() }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let intData = 1_234_567_890_123_456_789.data    // 8 bytes (64 bit Integer)
let dataToInt: Int = intData.integer                 // 1234567890123456789

let intMinData = Int.min.data                   // 8 bytes (64 bit Integer)
let backToIntMin = intMinData.integer           // -9223372036854775808

let intMaxData = Int.max.data                   // 8 bytes (64 bit Integer)
let backToIntMax = intMaxData.integer           // 9223372036854775807
```

---

```
let myInt32Data = Int32(1_234_567_890).data     // 4 bytes (32 bit Integer)
let backToInt32 = myInt32Data.int32             // 1234567890

let int32MinData = Int32.min.data               // 4 bytes (32 bit Integer)
let backToInt32Min = int32MinData.int32         // -2147483648

let int32MaxData = Int32.max.data               // 4 bytes (32 bit Integer)
let backToInt32Max = int32MaxData.int32         // 2147483647
```

---

```
let myFloatData = Float.pi.data                 // 4 bytes (32 bit single=precison FloatingPoint)
let backToFloat = myFloatData.float             // 3.141593
backToFloat == .pi      // true

let myCGFloatData = CGFloat.pi.data                 // 4 bytes (32 bit single=precison FloatingPoint)
let backToCGFloat = myCGFloatData.cgFloat             // 3.141593
backToCGFloat == .pi      // true

let myDoubleData = Double.pi.data               // 8 bytes (64 bit double-precision FloatingPoint)
let backToDouble = myDoubleData.double          // 3.141592653589793
backToDouble == .pi     // true

let myFloat80Data = Float80.pi.data             // 16 bytes (128 bit extended-precision FloatingPoint)
let backToFloat80 = myFloat80Data.float80       // 3.141592653589793116
backToFloat80 == .pi    // true

let decimalData = Decimal.pi.data             // 20 bytes Decimal type
let backToDecimal = decimalData.decimal       // 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419
backToDecimal == .pi    // true
```

Comment: Followup Questions:  The conversion to double doesn't work as intended.  Instead of return doubles around 100, the return values are tiny (on the scale of e-325).  This might have something to do with Big Endian/ Little Endian.  Do you have any solutions or places I might start looking for this?

Comment: @ChrisLowrie Can you post the data input, the type and expected output? are you sure your input is double 64bit (8bites) and the output is double also ? in you have only 4 bytes just create a float and initialize a double from it.  `Double(float)`

Comment: I have tested the double extension and it does work as expected. you need to show your actual code otherwise I would be just guessing

Comment: @ChrisLowrie yes, endianness is source of your trouble, if you don't have an access to ESRI documentation, check at least https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: This might crash with `Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data/38024025#38024025 for more info.

Comment: @Klaas it depends on how you are accessing the bytes of your data. You were probably accessing the bytes through subscript. You can use Data's subdata method to avoid this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530223/2303865