# Convert integer to array of UInt8 units

Tags: swift

I have number - 94887253 (in ASCII), it can be represented like:
let data = [UInt8]([0x39, 0x34, 0x38, 0x38, 0x37, 0x32, 0x35, 0x33])

How to write a function that convert number to such array of UInt8 units? Thanks.

Comment: How is `[0x39, 0x34, 0x38, 0x38, 0x37, 0x32, 0x35, 0x33]` related to the number `12345678`?

Comment: @MartinR its not related, 12345678 is random, like numbers i provided in hex.

Comment: But you still need to explicit the logic you want. ASCII? UTF8? Hex value (0xNM) is just another way to represent an Int, 1 == 0x01, no? What's the logic?

Comment: @MartinR i did edit my post.

Comment: @Larme its ASCII. My bad.

Comment: 0x39, 0x34, 0x38 are ASCII codes of the digits 9, 4, 8, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @MartinR yes but i need to write function for it.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban are you trying to convert Int to Data ? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244973/2303865

Comment: @Leo Dabus i succeed, thanks for Martin R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is an array with the ASCII
codes of the (decimal) string representation of the number:

```
let x = 94887253
let a = Array(String(x).utf8)

print(a == [0x39, 0x34, 0x38, 0x38, 0x37, 0x32, 0x35, 0x33]) // true
```

Comment: i tried let rCode = 94887253
        let arr = Array(String(rCode).utf8)
        print("arr? \(arr)") but  ended up with - [57, 52, 56, 56, 55, 50, 53, 51]

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban which is the same array. 57 in base 10 is `0x39` in hex.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban That's why I added the print statement: to demonstrate that the result is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would use shifts.

```
var array: [UInt8] = []
var n = theInputNumber
while n > 0
{
    array.append(UInt8(n & 0xff))
    n >>= 8
}
```

This is type safe and endian independent (the array is little endian but is easy to reverse) but slower than using an unsafe pointer.

**EDIT**

Right, so the question wasn't clear. If you want the ASCII represenatation of the number, the easy way is to turn it into a string and take the UTF-8

```
Array("\(theInputNumber)".utf8)
```

Or if you need to roll your own, modify my first answer

```
var array: [UInt8] = []
var n = theInputNumber
while n != 0
{
    array.append(UInt8(n % 10) + 0x30)
    n /= 10
}
```

The array is in reverse order, but I'll let you figure out how to get it the right way around.

Also will need modification for negative numbers.

Comment: You could use `insert(_ newElement: UInt8, at i: Int)` instead of `append` while adding elements, so that you don't have to reverse it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an ASCII codes of the decimal String representation of a number, you can write your own function for it like this:

```
func getAsciiCodesOfDigits(_ n: Int)->[UInt8]{
    return String(n).unicodeScalars.map{UInt8($0.value)}
}

getAsciiCodesOfDigits(numberToConvert)
```

Above function works, since using an `Int` as an input ensures that each element of `String(n).unicodeScalars` will be an `ASCII` character and hence it can be represented as a `UInt8` and for `ASCII` characters, `UnicodeScalar.value` returns the ASCII code in a decimal form.