# Reading Data into a Struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to read bare `Data` into a Swift 4 `struct` using the `withUnsafeBytes` method. The problem

The network UDP packet has this format:

```
data: 0102 0A00 0000 0B00 0000

01           : 1 byte : majorVersion      (decimal 01)
02           : 1 byte : minorVersion      (decimal 02)
0A00 0000    : 4 bytes: applicationHostId (decimal 10)
0B00 0000    : 4 bytes: versionNumber     (decimal 11)
```

Then I have an extension on `Data` that takes a `start` and the `length` of bytes to read

```
extension Data {
    func scanValue<T>(start: Int, length: Int) -> T {
        return self.subdata(in: start..<start+length).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    }
}
```

This works correctly when reading the values one by one:

```
// correctly read as decimal "1"
let majorVersion: UInt8 = data.scanValue(start: 0, length: 1)

// correctly read as decimal "2"
let minorVersion: UInt8 = data.scanValue(start: 1, length: 1)

// correctly read as decimal "10"
let applicationHostId: UInt32 = data.scanValue(start: 2, length: 4)

// correctly read as decimal "11"
let versionNumber: UInt32 = data.scanValue(start: 6, length: 4)
```

Then I created a `struct` that represents the entire packet as follows

```
struct XPLBeacon {
    var majorVersion: UInt8        // 1 Byte
    var minorVersion: UInt8        // 1 Byte
    var applicationHostId: UInt32  // 4 Bytes
    var versionNumber: UInt32      // 4 Bytes
}
```

But when I read the data directly into the structure I have some issues:

```
var beacon: XPLBeacon = data.scanValue(start: 0, length: data.count)

// correctly read as decimal "1"
beacon.majorVersion

// correctly read as decimal "2"
beacon.minorVersion

// not correctly read
beacon.applicationHostId

// not correctly read
beacon.versionNumber
```

I it supposed to work to parse an entire struct like this?

Comment: Note that you don't need to pass the length in your method signature. You can just use the size of your generic type `func scanValue<T>(start: Int) -> T {
        return subdata(in: start..<start+MemoryLayout<T>.size).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    }`

Comment: and change the naming `start` to `at`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the entire structure from the data does not work because
the struct members are *padded* to their natural boundary. The 
memory layout of `struct XPLBeacon` is

```
 A B x x C C C C D D D D
```

where

```
 offset    member
  0        A       - majorVersion (UInt8)
  1        B       - minorVersion (UInt8)
  2        x x     - padding
  4        C C C C - applicationHostId (UInt32)
  8        D D D D - versionNumber (UInt32)
```

and the padding is inserted so that the `UInt32` members are
aligned to memory addresses which are a multiple of their size. This is
also confirmed by

```
print(MemoryLayout<XPLBeacon>.size) // 12
```

(For more information about alignment in Swift, see
[Type Layout](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst)).

If you read the entire data into the struct then the bytes are assigned
as follows

```
 01 02 0A 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00
 A  B  x  x  C  C  C  C  D  D  D  D
```

which explains why `major/minorVersion` are correct, but `applicationHostId` and  `versionNumber`
are wrong. Reading all members separately from the data is the correct solution.

Comment: I indeed noticed the size of `MemoryLayout<XPLBeacon>.size` and was wondering why it's `12`. That explains a lot. I will use a custom initialiser even if it creates a lot of boiler plate code

Answer (score 6):

Since Swift 3 Data conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`, `MutableCollection`, `RangeReplaceableCollection`. So you can simply create a custom initializer to initialise your struct properties as follow:

```
extension Numeric {
    init<D: DataProtocol, R: RangeExpression>(
        _ data: D,
        range: R
    ) where R.Bound == D.Index, D.Index == Int {
        var value: Self = .zero
        let size = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, data[range].copyBytes)
        assert(size == MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value))
        self = value
    }
    init<D: DataProtocol>(
        _ data: D,
        index: D.Index = .zero
    ) where D.Index == Int {
        self.init(data, range: index...)
    }
    var byteCount: Int { MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: self) }
}
```

---

```
struct XPLBeacon {
    let majorVersion, minorVersion: UInt8             // 1 + 1 = 2 Bytes
    let applicationHostId, versionNumber: UInt32      // 4 + 4 = 8 Bytes
    init<D: DataProtocol>(data: D) where D.Index == Int {
        majorVersion = .init(data)
        var index = majorVersion.byteCount
        minorVersion = .init(data, index: index)
        index += minorVersion.byteCount
        applicationHostId = .init(data, index: index)
        index += applicationHostId.byteCount
        versionNumber = .init(data, index: 6)
    }
}
```

---

```
var data = Data([0x01,0x02, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00,0x00])
print(data as NSData)     // "{length = 10, bytes = 0x01020a0000000b000000}\n" <01020a00 00000b00 0000>

let beacon = XPLBeacon(data: data)
beacon.majorVersion       // 1
beacon.minorVersion       // 2
beacon.applicationHostId  // 10
beacon.versionNumber      // 11
```

Comment: This of course works but I was trying to avoid that as it creates a lot of boiler plate code but it looks like it's the only way.

Comment: Sure but there is no way to avoid this, MartinR explained in his answer the reason of the failure. Check my comment also above how you can improve your extension method,

Comment: Yes the answer from MartinR explains it well. Now I understand what was wrong. Thanks for your answer as well

Comment: Note that you can simplify to `data[0...0].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }` etc, you don't have to create an intermediate `Data` value.

Comment: @MartinR yes I don't know why it gave me another error I thought it was a slice issue

Comment: I would also added `guard` checking `data` length in the `init`, and made `init` failable.

Comment: @user28434 The data size will never change, So a guard there it is not needed. He can also check the data size before initialising the structure

Comment: Note that the data count doesn't guarantee it is the correct data

Comment: @LeoDabus, indeed, it doesn't guarantee that data is correct, but it does guarantee that your init won't crash app with fatal error during subscript with range, but instead will provide nice catchable error. Also, if this type is not private boilerplate, it's always good idea to check inside init, than hope that caller did checked it before.

Comment: He can also make it non fallible and throw an error. Thats not related to the question.

Comment: @LeoDabus, it is related to the answer, for it is comment to answer, and not  to the question. But anyways, it was just suggestion.

Comment: What I mean is we don't even know how OP is fetching the data so we don't even know if he needs it or not. Note that scanValue method would also crash if he pass the wrong length.

Comment: I did not mention on purpose how I get the data and whether it's valid or not to focus more on the question. Here we assume that the data does have the correct size.

Comment: There is a *potential* problem here. It is not *guaranteed* that `subdata(in:)` returns data with aligned memory, compare https://forums.swift.org/t/about-data-alignment/17447/2. That's why I recommended `copyBytes(to:)` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415. – There were suggestions to make `load(as:)` work with unaligned data, but as far as I can see, nothing happened until now.

Comment: @MartinR thanks Martin I thought that the problem was only happening when using subscript. I will check the links

Comment: @MartinR can you post an example where the approach above would fail? `var data = Data([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0x01,0x02, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00,0x00]).subdata(in: 7..<17)` works but `var data = Data([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0x01,0x02, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00,0x00])[7..<17]` doesn't.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I am afraid that I can't, that's why I said that it is a potential problem. It *seems* that `subdata(in:)` returns aligned memory, but nobody *guarantees* it. – That makes the `load(as:)` methods pretty useless in my opinion.

Comment: @MartinR I was checking the differences between the subscript and subdata implementations. subscript initialises a new Data object from the subsequence `public func subdata(in range: Range<Index>) -> Data {` `if isEmpty || range.upperBound - range.lowerBound == 0 {` `return Data()` `}` `let slice = self[range]` `return slice.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Data in` `return Data(bytes: buffer.baseAddress!, count: buffer.count)` `}` `}` Doesn't it guarantee that the data is aligned? https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Sources/Foundation/Data.swift

Comment: @LeoDabus: Probably, but I don't know! Even the constructor `Data(bytes:count:)` does not explicitly state that the copied memory has some minimum alignment. It probably is, but at present that seems to be an implementation detail (which is a bit unsatisfying).

Answer (score 0):

Following on Leo Dabus answer, I created a slightly more readable constructor:

```
extension Data {
    func object<T>(at index: Index) -> T {
        subdata(in: index ..< index.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<T>.size))
            .withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct XPLBeacon {
    var majorVersion: UInt8
    var minorVersion: UInt8
    var applicationHostId: UInt32
    var versionNumber: UInt32

    init(data: Data) {
        var index = data.startIndex
        majorVersion = data.object(at: index)

        index += MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: majorVersion)
        minorVersion = data.object(at: index)

        index += MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: minorVersion)
        applicationHostId = data.object(at: index)

        index += MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: applicationHostId)
        versionNumber = data.object(at: index)
    }
}
```

What is not part of this is of course the checking for the correctness of the data. As other mentioned in comments, this could be done either by having a failable init method or by throwing an Error.

Comment: I would also declare the properties constants. If you need to change the values better to create a new object