# Can’t build if memorylayout<>.stride and memorylayout<>.size different?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

in metal file,

1. Struct {
       float2
       float3
       float
       float
   } 
   size. 8+(8)+16+4+4=40
   stride. 48

---

2. Struct {
       float3
       float2
       float
       float
   }
   size. 16+8+4+4=32
   stride. 32

---

Using metal file, i made image filter. 
However Case 1 was implemented, but not 2.

Only size=stride can work?

Thank you!!

Comment: What error message or observable effect are you seeing as a result of this disparity?

Comment: I met this error message. <argument uniform[0] from buffer(1) with offset(0) and length(40) has space for 40 byte, but argument has a lengrh(48)>

Comment: This is due to the memory layout padding. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526132/2303865

Comment: Thanks @Leo  i wil try that solution