# How to interact with IOT Devices using BLE that does Request & Response with CheckSUM Logics in iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am using BLE with IOT Device. I need to send query request & response to IOT Device as below

The following is the typical query command syntax sent to device from the iOS

```
<STT><NOO><TAG BLOCK><INFO BLOCK ><CHKSUM><ETO>
```

Here, the TAG Block contains four bytes as described below

```
<ID><WID><SC><SO>
```

Can you suggest any tutorial or docs for sending request to IOT Devices.

Thanks IN Advance

Comment: Where did you get this information from? Sniffing?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to transform `Data` into a Custom Struct, like `struct Tag { let id, wid, sc, so }` etc.? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525922/reading-data-into-a-struct-in-swift ?

Comment: No. @Larme . I am looking to send Request to IOT devices with CHECKSUM logics and get Response from IOT devices....!

Comment: @Michael Kotzjan - Above is my requirement....!

Comment: ok, but what technology do you want to use? You tagged android, ios and objective-c. Do you want one app for multiple platforms?

Comment: I want to use Native Environment for iOS . Any documents & references that will be useful to implement it in Native Apps. @MichaelKotzjan

Comment: Just start with the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) and format your data the way you want. You could use the info from  the link @Larme posted or do something different. You can send all kind of data through BLE, you just have to process them correctly on the other side