# How to convert data containing various types of int into Swift Int

Tags: swift, integer, data-conversion

I receive Data type object which inside is list of uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t(mix typed list).
I need to convert this data into swift array of Int.
I cannot do the followings since data contains multiple types of int

```
let list = [Uint8](data)
let list2 = [Int](data)
```

Data order

- data1: uint8_t
- data2: uint32_t
- data3: uint16_t

How can I convert this type of data into Swift array of Int

Comment: You need to know exactly the order of those bytes and its endianness as well. You would need to provide more detail about your data structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Data into a Struct in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526132/2303865)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do type casting separately.

```
let list2 = [Int]()
for i in 0..<data.count {
    list2.append(Int(data[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Data` are bytes `[UInt8]` (with capital I) and `Data` are interchangeable.

For `[uint16_t]` and `[uint32_t]` use [MartinR's `Data` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data/38024025#38024025)

```
extension Data {

    init<T>(fromArray values: [T]) {
        self = values.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
    }

    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
        var array = Array<T>(repeating: 0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
        _ = array.withUnsafeMutableBytes { copyBytes(to: $0) }
        return array
    }
}
```

And an example, `uint16Bytes` represents an array of `[UInt16]` although the type is `[UInt8]`

```
let uint16Bytes : [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00]
let uint16Data = Data(uint16Bytes)

let array = uint16Data.toArray(type: UInt16.self).map(Int.init) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`toArray` returns `[UInt16]`. You have to `map` the array to `[Int]`

Comment: This does not answer what is being asked. "mix typed list" not a list of just UInt16 bytes.