# Reference to member 'subscript' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I need to convert an array of strings to integers.

```
import UIKit

var test = ["1", "2"]
let test1 = Int(test)[0]
let test2 = Int(test)[1]
print(test1 + test2)
```

^ this is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do, but I get "Reference to member 'subscript' cannot be resolved without a contextual type". Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the subscript on the `test` array, rather than on the result of `Int` initializer:

```
var test = ["1", "2"]
let test1 = Int(test[0])
let test2 = Int(test[1])
```

However, you can achieve what you are trying in an more swifty way:

```
var test = ["1", "2"]
print(test.compactMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +))
```

Or with just `reduce(_:_:)`:

```
var test = ["1", "2"]
print(test.reduce(0) { $0 + (Int($1) ?? .zero) })
```

Comment: or in a single iteration `test.reduce(0){ $0 + (Int($1) ?? .zero)}`

Comment: @LeoDabus hm, that's better. Thank you.

Comment: why should one use `.zero` over `0` here?

Comment: @Clashsoft there is no difference in this case. `.zero` is only needed when the actual type is not known https://stackoverflow.com/a/58420510/2303865. I prefer using `.zero` instead of `0` just for better readability. In fact it is just my opinion. Use whatever you feel comfortable with.