# Uint8 sequence padding with Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to do what we can easily achieve with [to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) with python, in Swift?

In a few words I need to define the length of a byte sequence, filling the leading elements with 0s.

As an example, if I have to describe the number 5 with a sequence of 4 bytes I should get it as `\x00\x00\x00\x05`.

with the python `to_bytes` function I can easily use the first parameter to define the sequence length and I could write it like `(5).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')` I can't find a way to easily obtain the same result with swift.

Comment: There is no “easy way” in the sense of a built-in function, as far as I know, but it should not be too difficult to implement (extract the lowest byte and divide by 256 in a loop). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415) is remotely related, but converts the integers to `Data` with their native sizes.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** Python's [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) can take any arbitrary `length`.  If you want to convert a value to its native size (eg. 1 byte for `Int8`, 2 bytes for `Int16`, 4 bytes for `Int32`, etc.), check out
>   [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1630618) and [How can I convert
>   data into types like Doubles, Ints and Strings in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43241845/1630618)

For any arbitrary length with sign extension (for negative numbers) you can use `& 255` to extract the lowest order byte and `>> 8` to shift the value right 8 bits repeatedly in a loop to compute the bytes.  (Here I used `map` to generate the array of bytes).  Then use `reversed()` to put them in the desired *big endian* order:

```
var i = 5
let len = 4

let arr: [UInt8] = (0..<len).map { _ in
    let byte = UInt8(i & 255)
    i >>= 8
    return byte }
    .reversed()

print(arr)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 5]
> ```

**Notes:**

- `>>=` will *sign extend* a negative number, so `-5` would give the expected 2's complement result: `[255, 255, 255, 251]`.
- Explicitly typing `arr` as `[UInt8]` ensures that `arr` is `[UInt8]` and not `ReversedCollection<Array<UInt8>>` *and* it aids Swift in the determination of the return type of `map`.
- For *little endian* order, remove `reversed()` and just use the result of the `map`.

---

#### Implementing `toBytes(length:bigEndian:)` as an `extension` of `Int`:

This can be added as an extension to `Int` to further mimic the behavior of Python's `to_bytes` method:

```
extension Int {
    func toBytes(length: Int, bigEndian: Bool = true) -> [UInt8] {
        var i = self
        let bytes: [UInt8] = (0..<length).map { _ in
            let byte = UInt8(i & 255)
            i >>= 8
            return byte
        }

        return bigEndian ? bytes.reversed() : bytes
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
print(5.toBytes(length: 4))
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 5]
> ```

```
print((-5).toBytes(length: 4))
```

> ```
> [255, 255, 255, 251]
> ```

```
print(5.toBytes(length: 8))
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> ```

```
print(5.toBytes(length: 8, bigEndian: false))
```

> ```
> [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> ```

---

#### Extending `toBytes` to work with any `Int` type

Simply extending `FixedWidthInteger` instead of `Int` makes this work for all `Int` and `UInt` types except for `Int8` which doesn't handle the sign extension correctly.  Checking for that type explicitly and converting it to an `Int` solves that problem.

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    func toBytes(length: Int, bigEndian: Bool = true) -> [UInt8] {
        if self is Int8 {
            return Int(self).toBytes(length: length, bigEndian: bigEndian)
        }

        var i = self
        let bytes: [UInt8] = (0..<length).map { _ in
            let byte = UInt8(i & 255)
            i >>= 8
            return byte
        }

        return bigEndian ? bytes.reversed() : bytes
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
print(Int8(-5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int16(-5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int32(-5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int64(-5).toBytes(length: 10))
```

> ```
> [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251]
> [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251]
> [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251]
> [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 251]
> ```

```
print(Int8(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int16(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int32(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(Int64(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(UInt8(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(UInt16(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(UInt32(5).toBytes(length: 10))
print(UInt64(5).toBytes(length: 10))
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> ```

```
print(UInt64.max.toBytes(length: 10))
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
> ```

Comment: The array initialiser is not needed. Btw it would be better to extend `FixedWidthInteger`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus.  I added the array initializer in the first case because I was ending up with `ReversedCollection<Array<UInt8>>(_base: [5, 0, 0, 0])` as the result instead of `[0, 0, 0, 5]`.  Explicitly setting the type of `arr` as `[UInt8]` solved that problem though.  `FixedWidthInteger` is a good idea, but it will still need a little work to do the right thing in the case of `UInt8`.

Comment: I meant `FixedWidthInteger` doesn't do the right thing with `Int8` and a negative number.

Comment: The generic approach. `extension Sequence where Element == UInt8 {`
    `var array: [UInt8] { .init(self) }`
`}`  
`extension Numeric {`
    `var data: Data {`
       `var source = self`
        `return .init(bytes: &source, count: MemoryLayout<Self>.size)`
    `}`
`}`
`Int32(-5).bigEndian.data.array` // [255, 255, 255, 251] https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244973/2303865