# Convert into generic function

Tags: swift, generics

I am writing an iOS app in Swift. My class has below functions for reading bytebuffer. Below all functions do same task but work on different number types. So, how to convert these functions into a single function using **generics**?

```
var array = [UInt8]()
private var currentIndex: Int = 0
private let hostEndianness: Endianness = OSHostByteOrder() == OSLittleEndian ? .little : .big
private var currentEndianness: Endianness = .big
  
public func getUInt16() -> UInt16 {
        let check=(currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size) - 1
        if array.indices.contains(check){
            let result = from(Array(array[currentIndex..<currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size]), UInt16.self)
            currentIndex += MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
            return result.littleEndian
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }

    
public func getInt32() -> Int32 {
    let check=(currentIndex + MemoryLayout<Int32>.size) - 1
    if array.indices.contains(check){
        let result = from(Array(array[currentIndex..<currentIndex + MemoryLayout<Int32>.size]), Int32.self)
        currentIndex += MemoryLayout<Int32>.size
        return result.littleEndian
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}

    public func getFloat() -> Float {
       let check=(currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size) - 1
       if array.indices.contains(check){
           let result = from(Array(array[currentIndex..<currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size]), UInt32.self)
           currentIndex += MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
           return Float(bitPattern: result.littleEndian)
       }else{
           return 0.0
       }
   }

   public func getDouble() -> Double {
    
    let check=(currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size) - 1
    if array.indices.contains(check){
        let result = from(Array(array[currentIndex..<currentIndex + MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size]), UInt64.self)
        currentIndex += MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size
        return Double(bitPattern: result.bigEndian)
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

*The only difference in the above functions is types: Float, double, UInt16, Int32.*

From Function:

```
private func from<T>(_ value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
        return value.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.load(fromByteOffset: 0, as: T.self)
        }
    }
```

**My Solution:**

```
    public func getNumber<T:Numeric>() -> T {
    let check=(currentIndex + MemoryLayout<T>.size) - 1
    if array.indices.contains(check){
        let result = from(Array(array[currentIndex..<currentIndex + MemoryLayout<T>.size]), T.self)
        currentIndex += MemoryLayout<T>.size
        return result.bigEndian
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

**Error:**

**Value of type 'T' has no member 'bigEndian'**

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. What's `from`? What's `currentEndianness`?

Comment: Also add your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: @DávidPásztor done

Comment: @SA that code still does not compile. What's `Endianness`? Where's the `from` method declared?

Comment: @DávidPásztor. Added from the method. littleEndian and bigEndian are already in Swift SDK Integer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, done. added my solution but i am getting error, Value of type 'T' has no member 'bigEndian'

Comment: @SA Only integers have bigEndian property

Comment: @LeoDabus, does Float, double, UInt16 and  Int32 come under 'Integer'? also, if I try <T:Integer>, it shows Use of undeclared type 'Integer'

Comment: You can use `FixedWidthInteger` protocol https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger thats where bigEndian property is declared

Comment: @LeoDabus, FixedWidthInteger includes Float, double, UInt16 and Int32 ?

Comment: Only integers. Double and float are FloatingPoint types

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244973/2303865 I don't know if the endianness will fit your purpose

Comment: @LeoDabus but double and float have bigEndian property as: DOUBLE.bitPattern.bigEndian, FLOAT.bitPattern.bigEndian

Comment: @SA the default is littleEndian you can always reverse the byte order before initializing your numeric type

Comment: the .bigEndian property is on its integer representation (UInt64) not on Double itself

Comment: "The only difference in the above functions is types: Float, double, UInt16, Int32."  - that's clearly NOT the only difference. You're using `UInt64`/`UInt32` for `Double`/`Float`, and the return statement is different. Not sure whether it's a copy-paste bug, but you're also using sometimes `.littleEndian` and sometimes `.bigEndian`. Generics might not be what you need here