# Convert Integer Array to Data

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

How can I convert an integer Array to Data?

This is what I have, but I am getting lost in figuring out the final step. I am only interested in the Swift 3 solution.

```
import Foundation

var buffer = [UInt64]( repeating: 0, count: 1000 )

for x in 0 ..< 1000
{
    buffer[x] = UInt64(x)
}

///////
// What goes here to place buffer into myData

var myData = Data()

//
///////
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/4763963) may help you. Check the second `extension` in **Generic solution #1**.

Comment: Your array should be an array of `UInt8`, not `UInt64` if you want each to represent one byte. But then each needs to be in the range 0...255. Or do you want each element of the array to represent 8 bytes?

Comment: Just a note, you can use one line to initialize your buffer: `let buffer = [UInt64](0..<1000)`

Comment: @rmaddy I have the same question as op, but I do need each element of array to represent 8 bytes. Following the the marked answer below, when printing `myData`, length is 32, when it should be 256, right? This might would explain why I dont get the expected value when converting that data to base64 string. what change is necessary? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want a `Data`, better check the initializers of `Data`.

[**`Data`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data)

`init<SourceType>(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer<SourceType>)` seems to be useful in your case, as `UnsafeBufferPointer` can easily made from `Array`.

```
var myData = buffer.withUnsafeBufferPointer {Data(buffer: $0)}
print(myData as NSData)
//-> <00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 02000000 00000000 03000000 00000000 ...
```

If the result is not what you expect, you need to explain it more.