# Creating NSData from unsafe pointer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

What's the Swift equivalent of:

```
var ed = NSData(bytes: &e, length: sizeof(e))
```

Comment: Where is the unsafe pointer? – Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data ?