# Converting Swift Data into Int16

Tags: java, ios, swift

I have a Java server where I take a `short[]` and I convert it to a `byte[]` (Big Endian) and I send it to an iOS device.  I am having trouble converting this byte array (or the `Data` in Swift) into an `int16` array (`[Int16]`).  I was also wondering if I was correct in assuming that the Swift equivalent of a Java `short` type is a `Int16` in Swift.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data.

Comment: java `short` and swift `Int16` are both 16-bit signed integers. So yes they are equivalent.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link, although this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @litelite Thank you for confirming my suspicion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similarly as in [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data) you can use the `withUnsafeBytes`
method and `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>` to get a view of the data as
16-bit integers. Then use the `Int16(bigEndian:)` initializer to convert
the numbers from big endian to host byteorder. Example:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 255, 255])
let i16array = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: data.count/2).map(Int16.init(bigEndian:))
}
print(i16array) // [1, 2, 256, -1]
```

Update for **Swift 5:**

```
let data = Data([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 255, 255])
let i16array = data.withUnsafeBytes {
        Array($0.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)).map(Int16.init(bigEndian:))
    }
print(i16array) // [1, 2, 256, -1]
```

Comment: @iCediCe: I have added a Swift 5 version.

Comment: `Array($0.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)) // little endian`

Comment: @WilliamEntriken: Strictly speaking, that would interpret the bytes as integers in *host* byte order. That happens to be little endian on all current platforms where Swift runs, but nothing prevents Swift from being implemented on a big endian architecture.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken yep - little endian was what I needed. I had unexpected behaviour using big. Thank you.