# swift 5 data.withUnsafeBytes

Tags: swift

Swift 4 code:

```
self.dataArray = data.withUnsafeBytes {
                    [UInt16](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: data.count))
                }
```

From looking at other answers to similar problems, I changed the above to:

```
self.dataArray = data.withUnsafeBytes {$0.load(as: [UInt16].self)}
```

The code compiles but gives me an exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: [Converting Swift Data into Int16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150010/1187415).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin R. The answer to my problem was:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes{ Array($0.bindMemory(to: UInt16.self))}
```