# How to convert Float to Data with BigEndian?

Tags: arrays, swift, byte, uint8t

I have:

```
Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
```

This code is converting data to float but I want reverse of it, means Float to Data. Please guide me how I can convert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a 32-bit integer with the big-endian representation of the
floating point number, then create a `Data` value from the integer
(as demonstrated for example in [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data)):

```
let value = Float(42.13)
var u32be = value.bitPattern.bigEndian
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &u32be, count: 1))
print(data as NSData) // <4228851f>
```

Verify the result by converting it back to a `Float`:

```
let v = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } ))
print(v) // 42.13
```

Comment: Thanks MartinR you rocked once again, is there any resource that will explain this type conversion ?