# Swift, How to read back Data into struct?

Tags: swift, serialization, swift3, casting, nsdata

The following piece of code takes a given `NSData` and "fills" it into a struct of type Container.

```
data: NSData ....
var tempBuffer: Container? = nil
data.getBytes(&tempBuffer, length: MemoryLayout<Container>.size)
```

How do I formulate this using `Data` instead of `NSData`? I simply do not understand how to formulate it in Swift. I guess you need `withUnsafeBytes`...

Thanks
Chris

Comment: It's recommended to use the native `Data` API `withUnsafeBytes`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data

Answer (score 0):

Since `Data` is convertible to `NSData`, you can use `as`:

```
let nsData = data as NSData
```