# Converting Data to SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am having an issue working with Data and SKSpriteNodes. Specifically, the conversion back from Data to SKSpriteNode. I have tried both methods of converting from data to something found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data), specifically this line:

```
    let data:SKSpriteNode = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &value, count: 1))
```

and I just cannot seem to get it to work. It always comes up with this error though:

```
    Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x600000123d40)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Am I trying to convert something too complex?

For reference, I am using iOS 10.3, Swift 3, and Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: Can you post the code relevant to the Data object and SKSpriteNode?

Comment: @Chris updated with the specific line

Comment: I don’t know much about pointers I’m afraid. Are you saving the data from a SKSpriteNode somewhere else? Why do you need to handle the SKSpriteNode this way?

Comment: For example, if you need to persist a sprite node’s data between app launches, you can use NSCoding (because the SKSpriteNode parent class SKNode inherits from NSObject).

Comment: I'm using this for multipeer connectivity, I've seen its best to send things as data through this