# Converting byte value correctly

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am having a hard time getting the correct value that I need.
I get from my characteristic vales from:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor ...
```

I can read and print off the values with:

```
let values = characteristic.value
for val in values! {
    print("Value", num)
}
```

This gets me:

```
"Value 0" // probe state not important
"Value 46" // temp 
"Value 2" // see below
```

The problem is that the temp is not 46.
Below is a snippet of instructions on how I need to convert the byte to get the actual temp. 
The actual temp was around 558 ºF.
Here are a part of the instructions:

```
Description: temperature data that is valid only if the temperature stat is normal
byte[1] = (unsigned char)temp;
byte[2] = (unsigned char)(temp>>8);
byte[3] = (unsigned char)(temp>>16);
byte[4] = (unsigned char)(temp>>24);
```

I can't seem to get the correct temp? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Others have answered your question, but I will pipe in to say to get rid of the `!` after `values`. If the `peripheral()` function returns `nil`, and your program uses the `!` operator on it, your entire program will crash. Instead, use `if let` or `guard let` to unwrap it, or use `?? []` to replace `nil` with an empty array.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I just wanted to make my question short. Probably bad practice, but you are right, it's too risky to just add !

Comment: What I do when I want to use a for loop like this is just to say `for val in values ?? []`. Almost as short, and won't crash.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I will have to try that if I don't check with an "if let".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the description, `value[1]` ... `value[4]` are the least significant to most significant bytes of the (32-bit integer) temperature, so this is how you would recreate
that value from the bytes:

```
if let value = characteristic.value, value.count >= 5 {
    let tmp = UInt32(value[1]) + UInt32(value[2]) << 8 + UInt32(value[3]) << 16 + UInt32(value[4]) << 24
    let temperature = Int32(bitPattern: tmp)
}
```

The bit-fiddling is done in unsigned integer arithmetic to avoid
an overflow. Assuming that the temperature is a *signed* value,
this value is then converted to a signed integer with the same
bit representation.

Comment: `UInt32(value[1]) + UInt32(value[2]) << 8 + UInt32(value[3]) << 16 + UInt32(value[4]) << 24` sounds like a job for its own `UInt32` extension.

Comment: @Alexander: Something like this: [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data) ?

Comment: @MartinR Yep :D Don't have time to look into that in detail right now, but is it ABI dependent?

Comment: @Alexander: If you think of byte order: No, my answer does not handle that, but it would not be difficult to add, using the bigEndian/littleEndian methods/initializers. It is partially handled in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41067342/1187415.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions tell you the answer. You are getting `46` in byte 1, then `2` in byte 2. The instructions say to leave byte 1 alone, but for byte 2 we are to shift the results as `temp>>8` — which means "multiply by `256`" (because `2^8` is `256`). Well, what is

```
46+256×2
```

It is `558`, just the result we're looking for.

Comment: You have no idea the headache you just saved me.

Comment: I don't think I would like to be in the room when byte 3 is needed.