# Swift 4 Int32 to [UInt8]

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to get the bytes from an integer into an [UInt8] to send them over a wire protocol. While I found answers that work for Swift 2/3, none of the solutions work for Swift 4.

The following snippet works to encode a message for small message sizes (just the raw string data prepended with a network byte order Int32 size):

```
func send(message: String) {
    let messageSize = message.utf8.count
    let encodedMessageSize = Int32(messageSize).bigEndian
    let frameSize = messageSize + 4

    var buffer: [UInt8] = Array()
    buffer.append(0)
    buffer.append(0)
    buffer.append(0)
    buffer.append(UInt8(messageSize))
    buffer.append(contentsOf: message.utf8)
    outputStream.write(buffer, maxLength: frameSize)
}
```

I have also tried using raw pointers directly, but cannot get anything to work for Swift 4 along that avenue either.

The overall tasks is to encode and frame messages that consist of integers and strings. The encoding converts everything to strings and adds a null at the end of each string. The framing simply prepends the message with a network byte order Int32 size. I cannot change the protocol, but am willing to consider other approaches to achieving this end.

cheers,

[EDIT] Updated code using @MartinR's code (with @Hamish's suggestion). Also made some progress of the overall task in the mean time.

```
func encodeMessagePart(_ message: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var buffer: [UInt8] = Array(message.utf8)
    buffer.append(0)
    return buffer
}

func encodeMessagePart(_ message: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    return encodeMessagePart("\(message)")
}

func frameMessage(_ buffer: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
    let bufferSize = buffer.count
    var encodedBufferSize = Int32(bufferSize).bigEndian
    let encodedBufferSizeData = withUnsafeBytes(of: &encodedBufferSize) { Data($0) }

    var frame: [UInt8] = Array()
    frame.append(contentsOf: encodedBufferSizeData)
    frame.append(contentsOf: buffer)
    return frame
}

func sendMessage(_ buffer: [UInt8]) {
    let frame = frameMessage(buffer)
    outputStream.write(frame, maxLength: frame.count)
}

func sendMessage(_ message: String) {
    let encodedPart = encodeMessagePart(message)
    sendMessage(encodedPart)
}

//    func sendMessage(_ messages: Encodable...) {
//        var buffer: [UInt8] = Array()
//        for message in messages {
//            let b = encodeMessagePart(message)
//            buffer.append(contentsOf: b)
//        }
//        sendMessage(buffer)
//    }
```

Comment: Note that `message.utf8` does *not*  add a null at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Data` value from the integer with

```
let encodedMessageSize = Int32(messageSize).bigEndian
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: encodedMessageSize) { Data($0) }
```

(In Swift versions before 4.2 you'll have to write

```
var encodedMessageSize = Int32(messageSize).bigEndian
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: &encodedMessageSize) { Data($0) }
```

instead.)

The data can then be appended to the array with

```
buffer.append(contentsOf: data)
```

Alternatively you can use a `data` buffer instead of an array:

```
func send(message: String) {
    let messageSize = message.utf8.count
    let encodedMessageSize = Int32(messageSize).bigEndian

    var data = withUnsafeBytes(of: encodedMessageSize) { Data($0) }
    data.append(Data(message.utf8))

    let amountWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { [count = data.count] in
        outputStream.write($0, maxLength: count)
    }
}
```

Finally note that that the `write()` method might write less bytes than
provided (e.g. on network connections), so you should always check
the return value.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &encodedMessageSize, count: 1))` isn't well defined, as the inout-to-pointer conversion for `&encodedMessageSize` produces a pointer only valid for the duration of the call to `UnsafeBufferPointer.init`. You could use `withUnsafeBytes(of:_:)` instead – e.g `withUnsafeBytes(of: &encodedMessageSize) { Data($0) }`. And in Swift 4.2+, `encodedMessageSize` can be a constant and passed non-inout :)

Comment: @Hamish: You are right (and I now I remember what I thought about it some time ago, but forgot about it again). It seems that I should use the weekend to rewrite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data :)

Comment: Hopefully a future version of the language prevents such temporary conversions for arguments of `Unsafe[...].init` calls (I've actually got an experimental branch going that does just that, but it needs a bunch more polishing before a PR), as IMO it's far too easy to accidentally do the wrong thing with them ([even the stdlib itself](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/18799) can get it wrong!).

Comment: @MartinR: What are the pro's / con's of using Data versus [UInt8]?

Comment: @RandomBits: There is a report that `Data` is slower than `Array` (https://forums.swift.org/t/performance-issues-with-foundation-data/16016) but that probably is only relevant for larger amounts.

Comment: (for anyone interested – [I've now opened a PR](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20070) to reject unsound pointer conversions and am hoping to merge at least the warning logic for Swift 5)