# Python struct.unpack("i", bytearray(data)) to Swift 4

Tags: python, swift

Python:

```
data = [0,0,0,0]
data[3]= self.i2cbus.read_byte_data(self.i2cadd, add)
data[2]= self.i2cbus.read_byte_data(self.i2cadd, add+1)
data[1]= self.i2cbus.read_byte_data(self.i2cadd, add+2)
data[0]= self.i2cbus.read_byte_data(self.i2cadd, add+3)
value = struct.unpack("i", bytearray(data))
return value[0]
```

How to do it in swift? I havde done this so far.

```
var data: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0]
data[3] = i2c.readByte(address, command: command) ?? 0
data[2] = i2c.readByte(address, command: command + 1) ?? 0
data[1] = i2c.readByte(address, command: command + 2) ?? 0
data[0] = i2c.readByte(address, command: command + 3) ?? 0
```

Using:
https://github.com/uraimo/SwiftyGPIO

It's the

```
    value = struct.unpack("i", bytearray(data))
```

I don't know how to do.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var value : UInt32 = 0
let nsdata = NSData(bytes: data, length: 4)
nsdata.getBytes(&value, length: 4)
value = UInt32(bigEndian: value)
```

Comment: You should rather use an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. `NSData` is also outdated, and has been replaced by `Data`. The only reason I see people still using `NSData` for, is because of `getBytes`, but there's no need for it with pointers.