# Convert Data? containing bytes to Int in swift 5

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I read from a characteristic of a ble peripheral on IoS some data, and when I try to print them, it just says 2 bytes. Looking at the type it is a optional Data type (Data?).

My question is, to convert that value to a readable integer, what is the best as fastest practice in swift 5?

If I try to print characteristic.value it just says "2 bytes". characteristic.value is an optional Data type.

```swift
switch characteristic.uuid:

   case accelerometerUUID:
      if characteristic.value != nil {
            let accelValue = ???
            print(accelValue)
      }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends. Could you do `print(characteristic.value as NSData)`. Depending on the result and what's the value behind it, you need to convert that String output into a String with `Int(String(data: characteristic.value, encoding: .utf8))` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
guard let value = characteristic.value else { return } // This makes it non-optional
let stringInt = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)
let yourNumber = Int(stringInt)
```

**This is much safer than the example below. The one above should be preferred.**

In one line of code:

```
let yourNumber = Int(String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf8))
```

**This is unsafe because you are unwrapping a value that might be optional, this can result in a crash.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it right now and I faced two issues; the first is that it keeps printing "2 bytes", and the second is that i needed to use the *guard* both for the stringInt and yourNumber value