# Are these memory functions the same for Swift 5 Conversion UnsafeBufferPointer

Tags: swift, generics, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am doing some Swift 5 conversion on code that I don't quite understand, legacy code from a previous developer.  I get:

> 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

for:

```
func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return self.withUnsafeBytes {
        [T](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
    }
}
```

I want to replace it with this but I am unsure if it does the same thing:

```
func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    var array = [T](repeating: 0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
    _ = array.withUnsafeMutableBytes { copyBytes(to: $0) }
    return array
}
```

Used in the context of these two fxs:

```
static func extractPacketSizeFromIV(iv: Data) -> Int32? {
    let array = iv.toArray(type: Int32.self)
    guard array.count == 4 else { return nil }

    let r0 = array[0].bigEndian
    let r1 = array[1].bigEndian
    let r2 = array[2].bigEndian

    return r2 ^ r1 ^ r0
}

static func extractGuidFromIV(iv: Data) -> Int32? {
    let array = iv.toArray(type: Int32.self)
    guard array.count == 4 else { return nil }

    let r0 = array[0].bigEndian
    let r1 = array[1].bigEndian
    let r2 = array[2].bigEndian
    let r3 = array[3].bigEndian

    return r3 ^ r2 ^ r1 ^ r0
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob I added more info for how they are used.

Comment: Your code looks like  the Swift 4 and Swift 5 versions from [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415) – you could have left a comment and ask for clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `toArray` is defined in an extension of `Data`, right?

(Please clarify such things when you write questions.)

Your code would work in the same way as the *code from a previous developer* in your use case, but I would write the equivalent in Swift 5 like this:

```
func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return self.withUnsafeBytes {
        [T]($0.bindMemory(to: type))
    }
}
```

`bindMemory(to: type)` creates an `UnsafeBufferPointer<T>` (as in the original code) from the parameter passed from new `withUnsafeBytes` - which is [`UnsafeRawBufferPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer).

Comment: The potential problem with bindMemory is that it requires the memory to be properly *aligned* for the bound type, and it is generally difficult to tell how the memory of a given data value is aligned. That's why I suggested copyMemory in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this question made it clear that the `Data` consisted of these three/four `Int32` values only, so I wouldn’t go about complicating this unnecessarily with `copyMemory` or what have you (esp if the buffer was large, homogenous collection). Sure, if you had a more complicated `Data` with heterogenous data types of different sizes, you’d take it to the next level, but not here, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the suggested replacement, namely [`withUnsafeBytes(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3139154-withunsafebytes), whose first parameter is a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, directly, not building an array or copying buffers unnecessarily, e.g.:

```
static func extractPacketSizeFromIV(iv: Data) -> Int32? {
    return iv.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer -> Int32 in
        let buffer = rawBuffer.bindMemory(to: Int32.self)
        let r0 = buffer[0].bigEndian
        let r1 = buffer[1].bigEndian
        let r2 = buffer[2].bigEndian

        return r2 ^ r1 ^ r0
    }
}
```

Obviously, if your `Data` was more complicated than this (e.g. a heterogenous payload with lots of different types of different sizes), different approaches might be called for, but if this is a simple buffer with just a simple collection of `Int32`, the above is an efficient way to retrieve the necessary values.

Comment: ... if the underlying memory is aligned for Int32 values.