# How to convert byte position in swift

Tags: swift, byte

How would I convert this properly? the value I need is byte number 0-1, has a format of uint16 and its units are in degrees.

```
print("derived : \(characteristic.value!)")
print(String(bytes: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf16))

derived : 20 bytes
Optional("\0{Ͽ⌜ƀ")
```

Comment: See [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the first two bytes of the `Data` as `UInt16`.

```
var result: UInt16 = 0
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &result) {characteristic.value!.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0...1)}
print("\(result) degrees")
```

Assuming your *format of uint16* is in Little-Endian as well as iOS, which is more often found in BLE characteristics.

(When you get the first value in `Data`, `from: 0...1` is not needed, but you may want some data in other position.)

Comment: ran and gave 0 degrees

Comment: @DisplayName, Then your `characteristic.value` holds `0` at _byte number 0-1_.