# How to convert NSData to custom object array in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I convert the `DrawObj Array` (custom object array)  to `NSData` and save it to cache directory use `NSFileManager` to save
then I use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL  options:0 error:&err]` to get NSData from filesystem 
Now I try to restore the NSData to  DrawObj Array ([DrawObjs])
How to do ?

I have try to use

```
extension Data {
    func elements <T> () -> [T] {
        return withUnsafeBytes {
            Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<T>(start: $0, count: count/MemoryLayout<T>.size))
        }
    }
}

if let objs:[DrawObj] = self.readFromFile()?.elements() {
    self.drawObjs = objs
}
```

but is crash[image]

**update show DrawObj model**

```
class DrawObj{

    var id : String!;
    var height : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var width : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var points:[CGPoint] = [];
    var oPoints:[CGPoint] = [];
    var angle : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var scaleX : CGFloat = 1.0;
    var oStartPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var oEndPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var scaleY : CGFloat = 1.0;
    var currentHeight : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var currentWidth : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var radius : CGFloat = 0.0;
    var drawPara : DrawParam = DrawParam();
    var text : String = "";
    var isFlip:Bool = false;
    var url:String = "";
    var image:UIImage?
    var fontSize : CGFloat = 16
    var originX:String = "left"
    var originY:String = "top"
    var pathPoint:[PathPoint] = []
    var stokeDashArray:[Int] = []
    var beizerPath:UIBezierPath?
    var nickName:String = ""

    init(id: String ){
        self.id = id;
    }

    init( id:String , drawType:DrawType , fillColor : DrawColor , stokeColor : DrawColor , lineWidth : DrawStokeWidth ) {
        self.id = id;
        self.drawPara.drawType = drawType
        self.drawPara.fillColor = fillColor
        self.drawPara.stokeColor = stokeColor
        self.drawPara.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }

}
```

Comment: Que!?  Why don't you use `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: get nil when use NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: datas)

Comment: This approach should work : https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/save-and-get-objects-using-nskeyedarchiver-and-nskeyedunarchiver-swift-5/

Comment: Can you please share your model object?

Comment: @EmreÖnder I have updated my question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data