# Issue Using Swift's withUnsafeMutableBytes Wrapper

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension to `Data` that allows me to extract it in various casts.

I'm running into a strange problem that I can't quite figure out.

Before I get into generics, I'm trying out fixed data types, and I created this method:

```
func intValueFromData(_ inData: Data) -> Int64? {
    var number = Int64(0)
    let len = Swift.min(MemoryLayout<Int64>.size, inData.count)
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number) {
        inData.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0..<len)
    }
    
    return number
}
```

That works. If I do this:

```
var int_64 = Int64(12345)

var data = Data(bytes: &int_64, count: MemoryLayout<Int64>.size)

let fetched = intValueFromData(data)
```

fetched becomes "12345" as an Int64.

However, when I try to embed the same method into the Data type, like so:

```
extension Data {
    mutating func intValueFromData() -> Int64? {
        var number = Int64(0)
        let len = Swift.min(MemoryLayout<Int64>.size, self.count)
        _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number) {
            self.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0..<len)
        }
        
        return number
    }
}
```

I get a compile-time error that says that "`withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number)`" is not supposed to have an argument.

The last time that I encountered something like this, it turned out that Apple explicitly blocked a functionality, but neglected to tell us in a straightforward manner.

I am not an expert at this kind of thing, but I am wondering if anyone could shed any light on why `withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number)` behaves differently inside the extension.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I needed to use Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes.

Comment: You can find that also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/1187415 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of `Data`, `withUnsafeMutableBytes` refers to `Data.withUnsafeMutableBytes(_:)`.

To disambiguate this and refer to the global function, explicitly prefix the module name: `_ = Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number) {`

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out. I had deleted the question, but I'll undelete in order to give you your greencheck. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMarshall You shouldn't delete questions just because you found the answer. Answer it yourself, so others can learn from you in the future.

Comment: Yeah...I'm a bit gunshy. I've been dinged for asking questions with obvious answers. I try to research each question as well as possible, but I'll admit to getting a bit steamed when someone tells me I'm...not so bright...because I missed an obvious point. Otherwise, I have no problem being wrong. I'm wrong all the time. That's how I become right.

Comment: BTW: I used this to create a pretty darn cool Data extension with a generic extractor. I'm writing the unit tests for it now, and will be adding it to my generic swift toolbox.

Comment: @ChrisMarshall I would just be *really* careful with that, because the moment there's a pointer involved, you open up a whole security can of worms

Comment: Good point. I *think* it is pretty safe, but, as you mention, there could be security issues. I'll post the method as another answer, and anyone that wants can take pokes at it. Peer review FTW.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the set, here's the generic function I created:

```
/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
// MARK: - Data Extension -
/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
/**
 This extension adds the ability to extract data fron a Data instance, cast into various types.
 */
public extension Data {
    /* ################################################################## */
    /**
     This method allows a Data instance to be cast into various standard types.

     - parameter inValue: This is an inout parameter, and the type will be used to determine the cast.
     - returns: the cast value (the parameter will also be set to the cast value). Can be ignored.
     */
    @discardableResult
    mutating func castInto<T>(_ inValue: inout T) -> T {
        // Makes sure that we don't try to read past the end of the data.
        let len = Swift.min(MemoryLayout<T>.size, self.count)
        _ = Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &inValue) {
            self.copyBytes(to: $0, from: 0..<len)
        }

        return inValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so folks know, this is part of [an open-source (MIT) utility](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox)

Comment: This overwrites by the bytes of `inValue`, without running a deinitializer. If `inValue` is a non-trivial type, this will leak memory (because its properties' reference counts would not have been deincremented on deinit) or cause other issues.

Comment: That's a good point. I really appreciate the feedback. I will see what I can do to mitigate that. I may have to restrict the types in the generic.

Comment: Swift doesn't have a way to express "trivial types only" in a generic constraint, as far as I'm aware. I think a better way to do this is by creating the value directly, rather than overwriting some existing value.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm seeing. I'm not sure how to do that without using explicit types (no more generic). I'll admit to not being a whiz with generics, though.

Comment: I'm likely to leave it in there as is, with a warning in the docs. I have a specific use case (Bluetooth Characteristic reading) that it's ideal for. I might be able to slap a precondition in there, so it pukes if someone tries to use a type other than the basics.

Comment: No, it doesn't puke, and that's the problem. If it was a compile time error, that would be fine. But it's not, it's a memory leak (that possibly also leaks other things, since people use RAII wrappers in Swift to model the lifetime of other resources like database connections, semaphores, file handles, network ports,etc.) I strongly suggest you change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212201/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-chris-marshall).

Comment: I did want to give a H/T to @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, as he was able to convince me that the hack (which is what it really is) did not belong in a publicly-released utility. I am quite used to strong pushback, having worked for Nikon for 27 years, and amongst some of the finest scientists and engineers in the world. I have strong opinions, and I'm smarter than the average bear, but I am often wrong, and learning that I'm wrong is one way to become right. That's one of the reasons that I like this place.