# What's an elegant way to do, or fake, 'type punning' in Swift

Tags: swift, type-punning

Writing in Swift, I have a specific need that might be a candidate for type punning.  I'm reading files from a disk image where they exist in contiguous 512 byte sectors.  A file comes off the disk as a `Data` struct which is easily converted to a byte array and/or 512 byte `DataSlices` without making copying necessary.

So far, so good!  A file can be represented quickly as a collection of arrays containing 512 `UInt8` units.  However, some disk sectors, typically containing metadata, are better treated as 256 `UInt16` items.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to refer to the sectors in memory either way without any copying.

Right now, I'm taking a simple approach in which I copy a sector (needing two copies) into something like:

```
struct Sector {
    let bytes: [UInt8]
    let words: [UInt16]
    . . .

init() {
    self.bytes = Array(repeating: 0, count: 512)
    self.words = Array(repeating: 0, count: 256)
    . . .
```

and then refer to `sector.words` or `sector.bytes` depending which is appropriate.  Luckily, the `[UInt16]` sectors are much fewer than their byte equivalents, so this isn't too awful; and any given sector is one or the other, I don't have to worry that changing `bytes` doesn't change `words` (although that's an accident waiting to happen).

Everything I read decries punning the `[UInt8]` and `[UInt16]` arrays, and Swift's "unsafe" memory functions are somewhat intimidating.  I'm trying to think of a way to make `.words` in the above struct occupy the same memory as `.bytes` and would appreciate some suggestions.

I'm still working on this .. if I find something worthwhile, I'll share.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024025/341994. Keep the data in a Data and access it as an array of UInt8 or UInt16 as desired. (Actually a Data *is* an array of UInt8, so you'd really only need to do anything special when you want to see it as an array of UInt16.) Example:

```
extension Data {
    init<T>(fromArray values: [T]) {
        self = values.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
    }
    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
        var array = Array<T>(repeating: 0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
        _ = array.withUnsafeMutableBytes { copyBytes(to: $0) }
        return array
    }
}

let eights : [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
let data = Data(fromArray:eights)
let sixteens = data.toArray(type: UInt16.self)
print(sixteens) // 513, 1027
```

That's the right answer, assuming the right endianity;

- `0b00000001` is 1
- `0b00000010` is 2

So, assuming lo-byte hi-byte:

- `0b0000001000000001` is 513

Answer (score 0):

Move that into the type!

```swift
struct Sector<Datum: FixedWidthInteger> {
  let data: [Datum]

  init() {
    data = .init(repeating: 0, count: 0x1000 / Datum.bitWidth)
  }
}

typealias Byte = UInt8
typealias Word = UInt16

Sector<Byte>().data.count  // 512
Sector<Word>().data.count  // 256
```

Comment: But then each sector can be seen only one way. The problem is to represent any given sector freely _either_ way. Basically it's a Swift version of a C union.

Comment: Protocols !