# Appending and extracting objects from NSMutableData

Tags: swift, nsmutabledata

I need to create create a data stream that contains multiple parameters, send it over the network and then extract those parameter when I receive the data.
This is how and create my data (I'm certain all of my variables contain a value)

```
 let dataToSend = NSMutableData()
 var mType = Int32(messageType.rawValue)
 var reqId = Int32(requestId)
 dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &mType, of: Int32.self)
 dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &reqId, of: Int32.self)
 /* extra protocol data length. In version 0, this is0 as thereis no extra data.
 In the future, if you need to add extra protocol data use this*/
 var unUsedProtocol = Int32(0)
 dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &unUsedProtocol, of: Int32.self)
 var encodedDataJson = !jsonString.isEmptyOrNil ? jsonString?.asciiValues : [UInt8]()
 dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &encodedDataJson, of: [UInt8]?.self)
 var bData = bindaryData
 dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &bData, of: Data.self)
```

here is my appendDataWithUnsafeBytes NSMutableData extension.

```
    extension NSMutableData {
        func appendDataWithUnsafeBytes<T>(from element: inout T, of type: T.Type) {
            let size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: element)
            withUnsafeBytes(of: &element) { ptr in
                let buffer = ptr.bindMemory(to: type)
                if let address = buffer.baseAddress {
                    self.append(address, length: size)
                } else {
                    VsLogger.logDebug("appendDataWithUnsafeBytes", "unable to get base address of pointer of type: \(type)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how try to extract it (I get the index value along with the data)

```
        var messageTypeValue: Int32? = nil
        var requestId: Int32? = nil
        var encodedJsonData: Data? = nil
        var binaryData: Data? = nil
        let intSize = MemoryLayout<Int32>.size
        let dataSize = MemoryLayout<Data>.size
        var offset = index
        
        bufferData.getBytes(&messageTypeValue, range: NSRange(location: offset, length: intSize))
        offset += intSize //8
        bufferData.getBytes(&requestId, range: NSRange(location: offset, length: intSize))
        offset += intSize //12
        /*skipping extra bytes (unsuedProtocol in sendMessageFunction). They come from a future version
         that this code doesn't understand*/
        offset += intSize //16
        bufferData.getBytes(&encodedJsonData, range: NSRange(location: offset, length: dataSize))
        offset += dataSize //32
        bufferData.getBytes(&binaryData, range: NSRange(location: offset, length: dataSize))
```

I'm only able to get the first value (messageTypeValue) but for the rest I either get nil or not the right data.

Thank you!

***** UPDATE *****

I got it working by modifying my sending and receiving functions as follows. Where I send it.

```
            let dataToSend = NSMutableData()
            var mType = Int32(messageType.rawValue)
            var reqId = Int32(requestId)
            dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &mType, of: Int32.self)
            dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &reqId, of: Int32.self)
            /* estra protocol data length. In version 0, this is0 as thereis no extra data.
             In the future, if you need to add extra protocol data use this*/
            var unUsedProtocol = Int32(0)
            dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &unUsedProtocol, of: Int32.self)
            var jsonData = Data(!jsonString.isEmptyOrNil ? jsonString!.asciiValues : [UInt8]())
            dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &jsonData, of: Data.self)
            var bData = bindaryData
            dataToSend.appendDataWithUnsafeBytes(from: &bData, of: Data.self)
```

where I receive it

```
        var offset = Int(index)
        let int32Size = MemoryLayout<Int32>.size
        let dataSize = MemoryLayout<Data>.size
        
        let messageTypeValue = (bufferData.bytes + offset).load(as: Int32.self)
        offset += int32Size
        let requestId = (bufferData.bytes + offset).load(as: Int32.self)
        offset += int32Size
        //skip this one since it not used
        //let unusedProtocol = (bufferData.bytes + offset).load(as: Int32.self)
        offset += int32Size
        let encodedJsonData = (bufferData.bytes + offset).load(as: Data.self)
        offset += dataSize
        let binaryData = bufferData.bytes.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: Data.self)
```

the data is supposed to always be align properly, but is there a way to do some error checking on `bufferData.bytes.load(fromByteOffset:as:)`

Comment: Consider to use native `Data` and suggestions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data

Comment: @vadian tried using the native Data, but I could't find a way to get it working with the different offsets of the objects in the data received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments I highly recommend to use native `Data`.

First of all you need [MartinR's Data extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data) to convert numeric types to `Data` and vice versa. I added an custom `append` method

```
extension Data {

    init<T>(from value: T) {
        self = Swift.withUnsafeBytes(of: value) { Data($0) }
    }

    func to<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
        var value: T = 0
        guard count >= MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value) else { return nil }
        _ = Swift.withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &value, { copyBytes(to: $0)} )
        return value
    }

    mutating func append<T>(_ other: T) {
        append(.init(from: other))
    }
}
```

This is a **very** simple version of your data set, three `Int32` values and a JSON array

```
let mType : Int32 = 1
let reqId : Int32 = 2
let unUsedProtocol : Int32 = 0
let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(["hello", "world"])
```

For convenience I omitted the error handling. In production code `try!` is discouraged.

The huge benefit of `Data` is that it can be treated as a collection type, an array of (`UInt8`) bytes. To build the `Data` package convert the numeric values and append the bytes respectively

```
var dataToSend = Data()
dataToSend.append(mType)
dataToSend.append(reqId)
dataToSend.append(unUsedProtocol)
dataToSend.append(json)
```

---

On the receiver side to extract the numeric values back this is a helper function which increments also the current index (as `inout` type), the byte length arises from the type. The function `throws` an error if the index is out of range and if the type cannot be converted.

```
enum ConvertDataError : Error { case outOfRange, invalidType}

func extractNumber<T : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(from data : Data, type: T.Type, startIndex: inout Int) throws -> T {
    let endIndex = startIndex + MemoryLayout<T>.size
    guard endIndex <= data.endIndex else { throw ConvertDataError.outOfRange }
    let subdata = data[startIndex..<endIndex]
    guard let resultType = subdata.to(type: type) else { throw ConvertDataError.invalidType }
    startIndex = endIndex
    return resultType
}
```

Get the start index of the data package and extract the `Int32` values

```
var index = dataToSend.startIndex

do {
    let mType1 = try extractNumber(from: dataToSend, type: Int32.self, startIndex: &index)
    let reqId1 = try extractNumber(from: dataToSend, type: Int32.self, startIndex: &index)
    let unUsedProtocol1 = try extractNumber(from: dataToSend, type: Int32.self, startIndex: &index)
    print(mType1, reqId1, unUsedProtocol1)
```

For the json part you need the length, in this example 17 bytes

```
    let jsonLength = json.count

    let jsonOffset = index
    index += jsonLength
    let json1 = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: dataToSend[jsonOffset..<index])
    print(json1)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: @I had something similar to that before but the issue I rant into was that I do not have access to the length of the json.

Comment: If the JSON represents an array or dictionary you can calculate the length: Get the first character (`{` or `[`) and increment a counter. Then walk through the bytes and increment the counter on an *open* character and decrement it on a *close* character. If the counter reaches zero the index is the position of the last character (`}` or `]`) of the JSON. The rest is a bit math.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the byte array represents a JSON **string**. If the first character is `[` the byte is 0x5b (or 0x7b for `{`). In my example the byte array is `<5b226865 6c6c6f22 2c202277 6f726c64 225d>`

Comment: gotcha! 
So after going through everything (again) I realized that I'm actually supposed to pass the length of the json as you mentioned. Just a honest silly mistake but thank you for sharing your thoughts, it helped my code a lot.