# How to convert Int8 to Data in swift

Tags: swift, data-conversion

Only examples I could find are about Uint8. How to convert Int8 to Data in Swift?

```
let int8Value: Int8 = -10
let data = int8Value.data // I need some extension like this
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415)

Comment: Please clarify what the intended result would be in your example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this simple extension to achieve your desired output.

```
extension Int8{
    var data:Data? {
        return "\(self)".data(using: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Comment: That would return the *string representation* of the number as UTF-8 data, in this case `2d 31 30`. That may be the desired result or not.

Comment: @MartinR What do you mean by this and why is it relevant? Data is always "String-representable", using one encoding or another. And, in the end, Data is Data.

Comment: @lazarevzubov: It is not clear to me what the desired result is. Is it the string representation of that number as data (in this case: `2d 31 30`) or the binary representation as data (in this case: `F6`)? I assume the latter, but clarification from the question author would be helpful.